# signaling keypress event in c

Tags: c, linux

Suppose I turn the terminal into "NON CANONICAL" mode the all the character editing is turned off.

1. Now what I want to do is to wait to for a keypress event  then when it happens I want to go to a function lets say "eat_input" then check there that if the key that was pressed is "arrow up" or "arrow down" key. If yes then convert the terminal into "NON CANONICAL" with option "TCSANOW"
   "eat" all the input that is not transmitted to the process then change the terminal back to "CANONICAL MODE".

Is there a way to do 1. in "c"(means wait for the keypress event).

Or is there another way to do 1. in c( Basically to eat the untransmitted input on the keypress event).

Comment: Not using only standard C, you have to use a library such as ncurses or use OS system calls directly. For example you could poll `STDIN_FILENO` for input, and read and parse the input yourself when that happens (cursor or special keys aren't input as single characters normally).

Comment: Ask ased, the correct answer would be "apparently there is". How do you think text-console editors work? Anyway, your question is too broad. There is all to be found by a simple search. This is no tutorial/consulting site. Time to start working yourself.

Comment: The simplest way to "eat input" is to put the terminal in nonblocking mode and then read input one character at a time until you get EWOULDBLOCK.  IIRC there isn't a termios primitive to do that.  But, before you waste a lot more time reinventing the wheel, look at [libreadline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) and [libncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO.html) and see if either of them does what you want.

Comment: @Olaf: Who is this ased? :) I know, "As asked".

Comment: You really, really do not want to do that, user3809584. Us "power-users" are really, really unhappy with programs that lose input. You might think "but this is so short a time interval that it does not matter in practice", but you're wrong; sometimes we type stuff lightning-fast (or have gadgets that supply inputs for us with keypresses at three-millisecond intervals -- USB HID, you see; 1 ms for press, 1 for release, and 1 for delay in between), or we run our stuff on an overloaded machine so that we *seem* to be too fast. Use Curses (easy and portable!), or redesign your input scheme.

Comment: @zwol: You can set the timeout to 1 (= 1/10s = 100 ms), in which case `read()` returns 0 (or -1 with errno==EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK; POSIX allows both) if there is no more input, after the timeout elapses. It's not terribly useful; sometimes multibyte keypresses get split. In Linux, one could use the FIONREAD ioctl() to find out if there is more input. The [termios](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) man page contains a description of the various VMIN/VTIME modes in the "Canonical and noncanonical mode" section.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Er, I meant "there isn't a termios primitive to eat input".  I know it's possible to do nonblocking I/O on terminals.

Comment: @zwol: [`tcflush(infd, TCIFLUSH)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html)?

Comment: @NominalAnimal Huh! I honestly did not know that existed.

Comment: POSIX termios interface is quite complex -- I think of it as "very configurable" -- so it's not something I'd recommend for use, unless there is particular reason to. Using **Curses** libraries is the better option -- especially since it is portable even to Windows systems! -- although I also consider *learning* a valid reason to use Termios directly. Should I show some example code for direct raw/non-canonical, non-blicking termios input? Would that help, user3809584? You'd still probably need to rethink your main loop structure, though; I don't think it'll "drop in" to your current design.